# Image Loading Slower

Tags: image, magento

I am showing images for flipkart and snapdeal products. They are been downloaded every time a user sends request. On a decent speed internet(not very high speed like 3G/4G), the loading takes way too much time, hence bad experience for user. However, the images which are on my server,even though they are 10 times in size, they get loaded very fast. Is there a way I can optimize these external images or any other way to enhance user experience

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if images are routed through your servers or directly from client, also it depends on number of request from client if it is due to request then you can load images on focus.

as of i now flipKart, snapdeal all are using cdn for faster static files with image sprite model so something at your code blocking the request or routed through your server.